# Fetching data from Multiple database in MongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo

I have a list of database name like this [client_db1, clientdb2,...].
There are total 300 databases.

Now each database has a collection with same name as **secrets**.

I want to fetch records from each collection so I will get 10-15 (not more than this) records from each collection.

In my code base,
we iterate through each database and then create a dataframe.

```
combined_auth_df = pd.DataFrame()
for client_db in all_client_dbname_data:
    auth_df = get_dataframe_from_collection(client_db)
    combined_auth_df = combined_auth_df.append(auth_df, ignore_index=True)
```

This process is taking a lot of time.
Is there any good way to do this. Also I am curious if we can do the same with multithreading/multiprocessing.

Comment: Reading from the database is network-bound and can be done using multiple threads.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule But using multiple threads how can i write data to same dataframe ?

Comment: You can have each thread return a DataFrame of the collection. After synchronizing each thread, their results can be combined using `pandas.concat` function.